# how to display dynamic data with limit in 3 column grid with angular ionic

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have dynamic data which is showing in unordered list as follows in ionic angular

```
<div *ngIf="personNameArray.length">{{'Selected People:'|translate}}</div>
              <div class="ion-margin-start" *ngIf="personNameArray.length">
                <ul>
                  <li *ngFor="let name of personNameArray">
                    {{name}}
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
```

I need to show 'personNameArray' data in 3 columns grid having distributing records equally  . How should I do that?
Please guide. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

#### Distribute array values evenly across multiple columns

I created two solutions: One where the values are filled in from the left to the right and one where they are filled from top to bottom. Both solutions are generic in the sense that you just have to change the value of the `numberOfColumns`-variable and the UI will adapt accordingly.

***Variant 1 - Fill values from left to right***

Desired Output:

```
'1 Tom'    | '2 Luke'  | '3 Torsten' |
'4 John'   | '5 Mike'  | '6 Emily'   |
'7 Jessica'| '8 Jacob' | '9 Madison' |
'10 Ethan' | '11 Matt' |
```

**TS-File:**

```
numberOfColumns = 3; // The number of columns can be changed as desired

names: string[] = ["1 Tom", "2 Luke", "3 Torsten", "4 John", "5 Mike", "6 Emily",
                   "7 Jessica", "8 Jacob", "9 Madison", "10 Ethan", "11 Matt" ];

get gridSpecification(): string {
    return `repeat(${this.numberOfColumns}, 1fr)`;
}
```

**HTML-File:**

```
<ul [style.display]="'grid'"
    [style.grid-template-columns]="gridSpecification">

    <li *ngFor="let name of names">
        {{name}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

---

***Variant 2 - Fill values from top to bottom***

Desired Output:

```
'1 Tom'    | '5 Mike'    | '9 Madison' |
'2 Luke'   | '6 Emily'   | '10 Ethan'  |
'3 Torsten'| '7 Jessica' | '11 Matt'   |
'4 John'   | '8 Jacob'   |
```

**TS-File:**

Let's re-arrange the array-elements in a way that the html-part of solution 1 can be reused:

```
numberOfColumns = 3; // The number of columns can be changed as desired

names: string[] = ["1 Tom", "2 Luke", "3 Torsten", "4 John", "5 Mike", "6 Emily",
                   "7 Jessica", "8 Jacob", "9 Madison", "10 Ethan", "11 Matt" ];

reOrderedNames: string[] = [];

get gridSpecification(): string {
    return `repeat(${this.numberOfColumns}, 1fr)`;
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    const arrayOfBatches = this.splitIntoBatches(this.names, this.numberOfColumns);
    this.reOrderedNames = this.zip(arrayOfBatches).flat();
}

private splitIntoBatches(arr: string[], numberOfBatches: number): string[][] {
    // 'max batch size' equals 'max column length'
    const maxBatchSize = Math.ceil(arr.length / numberOfBatches);

    // 'number of batches' equals 'number of columns'
    return  Array.from({ length: numberOfBatches },
                        (_, i) => arr.slice(i * maxBatchSize, (i + 1) * maxBatchSize));
}

private zip(arr: string[][]): string[][] {
    // 'max array length' equals 'max column length'
    const maxArrayLength = Math.max(...arr.map(a => a.length));

    return Array.from({ length: maxArrayLength },
                     (_, i) => arr.filter(a => !!a[i]).map(a => a[i]));  
}
```

**HTML-File:**

```
<ul [style.display]="'grid'"
    [style.grid-template-columns]="gridSpecification">

    <li *ngFor="let name of reOrderedNames">
        {{name}}
    </li>
</ul>
```